# How can I change the URL of my IIS published web application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

This is my first time publishing my visual studio project. I am using IIS manager to publish it. My server name is KIMSERVER and the port I have now is 97. Thus when I need to launch the web app I saved I need to type KIMSERVER:97/
Is there any way that I can change the URL to KIMSERVER/WebApp1 or any URL I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Virtual Directory in your Sites App Pool (Name it WebApp1 and it should be possible to connect via KIMSERVER/WebApp1).
After you published to it, its converted to an application.

Comment: No Problem. May close this question to mark it as helpfull in the overview :-).